# Remove trailing newline character using fgets

Tags: c, token, fgets

I am making a program to read a file and determine if a word is a palindrome. I am running into an issue where the last token has a trailing newline and won't register as a palindrome.

Here is the file input:

```
leVel CompUtER Science theORY radar
```

And this is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void palindrome(char str[]){
  int length = strlen(str);
  int i = 0;
  int j = length - 1;
  for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if(str[i] != str[j]){
      printf("String %s is not a palindrome.\n", str);
      return;
    }
    j--;
  }
  printf("String %s is a palindrome.\n", str);
  return;
}



int main() {

  char line1[100];
  fgets(line1, 100, stdin);
  printf("%s", line1);

  char *token;
  token = strtok(line1, " ");

  while(token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", token);
    palindrome(token);

    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use `" \n"` ad delimiter, it will get rid of the newline as well.

Comment: @Pablo has a sufficient answer, but a nice piece of reusable code to trim newlines and more from buffers is `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `strtok`, then you can use `" \n"` as the delimiter and the newline will be taken care of.

```
int main() {

  char line1[100];
  fgets(line1, 100, stdin);
  printf("%s", line1);

  const char *delim = " \n";

  char *token;
  token = strtok(line1, delim);

  while(token != NULL){
    printf("%s\n", token);
    palindrome(token);

    token = strtok(NULL, delim);
  }

  ...

}
```

Another great method to remove the newline is to use `strcspn` like this:

```
char line[1024];
fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);

line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = 0; // removing newline if one is found
```

Comment: Thinking Windows, It shall be better to use: `line[strcspn(line, "\r\n")] = 0;`!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use fgetc and stop at the newline? You could also even just find the newline character in the string and assign '\0' to it, and it will be gone.